# How to Generate Unique Full Names from $names[], $surnames[]?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, generator

I have two arrays (actual size is 10x bigger):

```
$names = array(
    'James',
    'John',
    'Robert',
    'Michael',
    'William'
);

$surnames = array(
    'Smith',
    'Johnson',
    'Williams'
);
```

I need to generate people's full names. One person can only have one name and one surname. Full names must be unique! What's the best solution?

P.S. I don't need all possible names. I think that when there can't be made any other unique full names from given arrays... I will throw an exception!

*Solution #1:*

The first one that came in my mind...

Create new array called `full_names` and store generated names in there. Before storing, check that there aren't such value already. Generate by random.

**This gonna be so slow! And stupid.**

*Solution #2:*

Ask on StackOverflow.com algorithm for generating all possible full names... and then take only that much as I need. **No, this sounds stupid as well...**

Comment: You just want ordered doubletons `(i,j)` with `i` the index of the  name and `j` the index of the surname, right? Just loop through.

Comment: Nobody will ever suspect The Spanish Inqui- uh, John Johnson or William Williams.

Comment: @PengOne Yep, that was so easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an array of `(i,j)` integer doublets covering all possible name-surname combinations.  Shuffle the array.  Then just loop through the array, and take names from it one by one.

You'll get unique full names in random order (provided that your name and surname lists don't contain duplicates).

**EDIT**

Pseudocode, per request.

First, do these setup steps:

```
indexList = emptyList
for i = 1 to length(first_names)
  for j = 1 to length(last_names)
    indexList.push( (i,j) )

shuffle(indexList)
```

`push` here means adding an element to the end of the list.

Now every time you need a new name, just take one index pair off `indexList`, and return the corresponding names from the name arrays:

```
function getName()
  (i, j) = indexList.pop()
  return concatenate(first_names[i], " ", last_names[j])
```

`pop` here means remove an element from the end of the list and return it.  It is unlikely that you'd have so many names that the `indexList` should take up too much memory.

Comment: @daGervis, see my edit.  If your question is about how to implement this in PHP, then I can't help unfortunately, and I'll delete my answer.  If your question is about an algorithm for returning random, never-repeating names, then hope this helps.

Comment: @daGervis, if you don't have a built-in shuffle function in your language, there are easy to implement hacks for that too.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the first and last names, check if you already generated that combination. In PHP:

```
$full_names = array();
foreach ($names as $first_name) {
    foreach ($surnames as $last_name) {
        $candidate = $first_name . " " . $last_name;
        if (!isset($full_names[$candidate])) {
            $full_names[$candidate] = true;
        }
    }
}

print_r(array_keys($full_names));
```

Or same in Python:

```
print set([first + ' ' + last for first in names for last in surnames])
```